# Styling (blur) a SVG with class via CSS

Tags: css, svg, path, styles, svg-filters

I am trying to style some Path/SVG-Elements with CSS. In particular I am trying to apply a blur to their borders. 
Since the Elements are created from a library (leaflet.clustermarkers) I can not control the creation of the SVG/Path-elements themselves. The library offers to give the elements a "class" that I can use to select them via CSS.

So the following works:

```
.poligonArea{  

  fill:black;

}
```

but the following only works in firefox but neither in Chrome, nor in Safari:

```
.poligonArea{  

  fill:black;
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Why doesn't it work in Chome/Safari? They should support the svg-filters, no?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter <- Especially the part on SVG filters.

Comment: So does that mean, that basically only Firefox and Edge support Filter:blur on SVG-Elements?!
(Looks like it under "Browser compatibility" in your link)

Is there any other way to apply a blur or at least a blurred border in my case?

Comment: Unprefixed should always come after prefixed in CSS. If that's not the problem, then element level support for CSS filters is ongoing in SVG and if it doesn't work, you'll have to use an SVG filter directly. Google SVG Filters if you need to know how they work - there's lots of docs out there.

Comment: Oh yes the prefix ... sorry for that. In my file I have them all before the unprefixed one. No matter which way around it did not work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did the following which seems to work

I added this svg-tag with the specified filter (in my case I want the Gaussian Blur) to the index.html/DOM

```
<svg>
<defs>
    <filter id="mySVGfilter" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5"/>
    </filter>
</defs>
```

(width="200%" height="200%" are making sure that my blur doesnt get cut off from the element borders)

then in the css-file I added this:

```
.poligonArea{

  fill:black;
  filter: url('#mySVGfilter');
}
```